# How to connect navigation item button to a view controller in swift?

Tags: swift, segue

How can I connect this button to a view controller screen when tapped?

```swift
func setupRightNavItems() {        
    //apple music button
    let appleMusicBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
    appleMusicBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "apple_music")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [/UIBarButtonItem(customView: spotifyBtn),/ UIBarButtonItem(customView: appleMusicBtn)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you want exactly by create a UIButton, but you can create a UIBarButtonItem with an image, instead of create a button.

Anyway, the way you get the action is by adding a target, usually self, but you can link to another object that will manage your navigation actions, and a function.

It works the same way if you embed your button.
See available inits here :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem

```
class MyViewController {

    func setUpNavigationItems() {
        let appleImage = UIImage(named: "apple_music")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        let spotifyImage = UIImage(named: "spotify")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [
            UIBarButtonItem(image: appleImage, style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(appleTapped)),
            UIBarButtonItem(image: spotifyImage, style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(spotifyTapped))
        ]
    }

    @objc func appleTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
   
    }

    @objc func spotifyTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Moose. That helps a lot. But how do I call the view controller inside the obj? I know this must be pretty basic but I am new to swift and have been going in circles for hours

Comment: I just add the view controller in my answer if it can help. I guess you already have it

Comment: The view controller is called by setting the target to self - since the function is declared inside itself - and you simply pass the name of the function to call as a selector in the action parameter )